# Shouldn't some questions be region dependent?

Tags: discussion, tags

[I have done a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352081/whats-the-term-for-government-worker/352322#352322) and the answers where many and highly region dependent, there was different perspectives from countries such as India, USA, UK, Australia on how to say something in English.

How to indicate a question should be region dependent? Should a question address a particular region, or one question per word with all the regions responded in answers?

What I want to know, it's how it's managed for example when a certain concept has different words in different places, countries , around the world.

Comment: Add a tag for the regions if differences come up

Answer (score 6):

As Mitch already says in the comment, we have tags for different variations of English. They are manifested on ELU in the tags like [american-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-english), [british-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-english), [indian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-english) and [australian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-english).

We do not have tags for geographic regions per se. However, I don't see any reason for that. The amount of questions where it is relevant and not matching the English variation in use in that geography is likely minuscule.

Comment: Thanks, So, if say the word "rice" has three different meanings in three countries, then it's better to make three questions each marked regionally, instead of one with three answers by region?

Comment: @Santropedro if is specifically about the differences between the variations it can be one question. A question can take up to five tags. Generally in the SE model a question should just aim for one answer. Of course making a distinction between two meanings can be within one answer. In depth analyses about a word's meaning in a specific region however validate their own questions.